# Build and install aerospike 4.0.0 in python 3.8 alpine 3.16

Tags: python, alpine-linux, aerospike

I am trying to install aerospike for python 3.8.14 on alpine 1.16.2.
Following offical documanetion I've already built aerospike-client-c 4.6.18 (release), successfully installed aerospike using pip.

Problem is that I got following error:
`uv_async_send: symbol not found`

```
ImportError: Error relocating /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aerospike.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: uv_async_send: symbol not found
```

I've tried use ./install_libuv in aearospike-c-client but it didn't help.

I am not familair with all these building stuff, so maybe I am missing something.

Any ideas I can work out?

Command that failed:

```
python3 -c 'import aerospike'
```

My current Dockerfile:

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.8

FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}-alpine as aerospike-c-builder
ENV AS_C_VERSION=4.6.18
WORKDIR /src

RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    build-base \
    bash linux-headers \
    libuv libuv-dev \
    openssl openssl-dev \
    lua5.1 lua5.1-dev zlib-dev
RUN wget https://artifacts.aerospike.com/aerospike-client-c/${AS_C_VERSION}/aerospike-client-c-src-${AS_C_VERSION}.zip \
    && unzip aerospike-client-c-src-${AS_C_VERSION}.zip \
    && mv aerospike-client-c-src-${AS_C_VERSION} aerospike-client-c \
    && cd aerospike-client-c \
    && make EVENT_LIB=libuv


# Stage 2: Build Aerospike Python client
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}-alpine as aerospike-python-builder
ENV AS_PYTHON_VERSION=4.0.0
WORKDIR /src
COPY --from=aerospike-c-builder /src/aerospike-client-c/target/Linux-x86_64/ aerospike-client-c/

ENV PREFIX=/src/aerospike-client-c/
RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    build-base \
    bash \
    linux-headers \
    zlib-dev \
    openssl-dev \
    git
ENV DOWNLOAD_C_CLIENT 0
RUN pip --no-cache-dir install aerospike==${AS_PYTHON_VERSION}
```